# Propriedade está vindo como Undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda

No controller eu tenho uma lambda que me retorna três campos. Quando eu rodo no jquery me diz que a propriedade é Undefined. Acho que é a forma como eu tento pegar o valor. Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda aí?

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CarregaDadosPagina(int _nivel)
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

            UsuarioNivel us = new UsuarioNivel();

            var result_carrega_pagina = db.Usuario
                .Where(n => n.IDUsuario == _nivel)
                .Select(s => new {s.NM_Usuario, s.Usuario1, s.Email }).ToList();

            return Json(result_carrega_pagina, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

JQuery:(NM_Usuario é Undefined)

```
function CarregaDados(ajaxParameter) {

    var str = "";

    $.ajax({

        url: '/CadastroAcesso/CarregaDadosPagina',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ _nivel: ajaxParameter }),
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data.result_carrega_pagina.NM_Usuario);
        },
        error: function (error) {

            alert(2);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Se tu estás a retornar uma lista, tens de percorrer um .each para apresentar `data.result_carrega_pagina.NM_Usuario`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pnet, estás a retornar uma lista do teu controller, e ao fazer um alerta do `data.result_carrega_pagina.NM_Usuario` dá `undefined`, porque na verdade a propriedade não existe.

Para dares `alert` podes percorrer um `.each` com o teu `data`:

```
success: function (data) {
   $.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
       alert(itemData.NM_Usuario);
   });

}
```

Comment: Ok, resolveu. Deixa passar os 7 minutos e já marco a resposta. Valeu Cesar Miguel. Fiz o each errado. Eu fiz assim: $(data.result_carrega_pagina).each(function (){})